# Save Datetime from C# to MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I try to save Datetime value from C# to MongoDB with value :

```
DateTime.ParseExact("10/02/2015", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

But in MongoDB show up :

```
ISODate("2015-02-09T17:00:00.000Z")
```

I don't know why MongoDB result later than one day (date : 9) while my date is 10. Thanks for your reading my question

Update 1 : As #mnemosyn's answer i do some change :

```
DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime.ParseExact("20/07/2015", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)), DateTimeKind.Utc)
```

Result : `ISODate("2015-07-20T00:00:00.000Z")`

More detail : [DateTime.ToLocalTime Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: What timezone are you in?

Comment: my Timezone is : GMT+7

Comment: (UTC+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta

Comment: You should't add the answer to the question, instead you should create a new answer to the question containing the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the parsed date is not considered a UTC date. 02-09+7h is exactly 02-10...

`DateTime` has a property called `Kind` which of type `DateTimeKind`. These can be `Local`, `UTC` or `Unspecified`. If the string you're parsing doesn't indicate which one it is, [the returned `DateTime.Kind` will be `Unspecified`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx). The MongoDB driver then converts this to UTC because that is, more often than not, what people expect when they think of `DateTime`.

Note that the mantra 'always store UTC in the database' isn't always true, e.g. for a bus schedule.